# How to count the bytes in RAW to make 16,24,32 bytes to use with AES encryption

Tags: r, aes

I'm trying to make a R code that do some things to store a sensitive data, until that all ok.
So, my problem is the bytes of the cyphertext and key, how to make the RAW of key and cyphertext 16,24 or 32 effiencily ?

```
library(digest)

key <- charToRaw("keymusbe162432bytes")
aes <- digest::AES(key, mode="ECB")
pass1 <- paste0(pass,"textHereIsNotTheSame")
rawcypher <- charToRaw(pass1)
aes$encrypt(rawcypher)
aes$decrypt(aes$encrypt(raw), raw=FALSE)
```

```
Error in digest::AES(key, mode = "ECB") : 
  AES only supports 16, 24 and 32 byte keys
```

Comment: ```> typeof(aes)
[1] "list"
> class(aes)
[1] "AES"```
a object that contain the result of funtion, sorry, just see, updated there

Comment: It is there in the documentation `The key as a 16, 24 or 32 byte raw vector for AES-128, AES-192 or AES-256 respectively.`

Comment: my questions is: 1bytes its equal to 1raw ? just that? i'm overcoplicating this ? because if my concept of bytes and raw are correct I can solve by my own the rest.

Comment: It seens I wanna that AES could handle more types of ASCII, just that

Comment: make the characters to either 16 or 24 or 32 i.e. `key <- charToRaw("keymusbe162432bytessssss")#
> AES(key, mode = 'ECB')#
AES cipher object; mode ECB key size 24`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `?AES`

> key - The key as a 16, 24 or 32 byte raw vector for AES-128, AES-192 or AES-256 respectively.

That implies if it is not exactly 16 or 24 or 32, will result in error

```
AES(as.raw(1:16), mode = "ECB")
#AES cipher object; mode ECB key size 16 

AES(as.raw(1:17), mode = "ECB")
```

> Error in AES(as.raw(1:17), mode = "ECB") : 
>         AES only supports 16, 24 and 32 byte keys

```
AES(as.raw(1:24), mode = "ECB")
#AES cipher object; mode ECB key size 24
```

---

With the OP's code, we could make the characters to 16 or 24

```
key <- charToRaw("keymusbe162432bytessssss")
AES(key, mode = 'ECB')
#AES cipher object; mode ECB key size 24
```